# Add a custom widget in a CoolBar?

Tags: java, swt, jface

Is it possible in a standalone SWT/JFace application to add a custom widget in a CoolBarManager (a text box for exemple) ?

I look for IContributionItem but I didn't find useful examples.

HelpSearchContributionItem seems to work only with a RCP application (it uses objects from RCP : IWorkbenchWindow for example).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should subclass ControlContribution and implement createControl() method.

Then add a `ToolBarManager/ToolBarManagerContributionItem` to the coolbar, and your subclass of `ControlContribution` to the `ToolBarManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is **not** recommended, you can subclass the ToolItem class and provide your own implementation. To do this you also have to override the checkSubclass method.

```
public class MyToolItem extends ToolItem {
    @Override
    protected void checkSubClass(){
        // leave it empty
    }
}
```